# SQL join with composite key

Tags: sql

I'm struggling with a SQL join query, maybe you could help me.

I have to join two tables. In one table, the primary key is a composite key from two columns to uniquely define a row.

In the other table, I just have one of these two rows.

Table looks like this:

| Table 1 |
| --- |
| Type (PK) |
| Code (PK) |
| Description |

f.e.

| Type | Code | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | potential A |
| 0 | A+ | potential A+ |
| 1 | 1 | Premium |
| 1 | 2 | Mainstream |
| 2 | EFI | EFI |
| 2 | LK | Local Key |
| 3 | 100 | exclusive |
| 3 | 105 | inclusive |

In the second table, I have the code as the foreign key, but multiple times:

| Table 2 |
| --- |
| Number (PK) |
| Name |
| Address |
| Code 1 (FK) |
| Code 2 (FK) |
| Code 3 (FK) |

I want a query, where it shows me, f.e the customer name, code 1, code 2 and code 3 and the corresponding description.

If I have a query like this:

```
SELECT a.Number, a.Name, a.Code1, b.description, a.Code2, b.description
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table2 b ON a.Code1 = b.Code
```

it always shows me the first description. So, if Code 1 = A -> Description: potential A, if Code 2 = 1 -> Description = potential A - even if the correct description is "Premium".

I hope it's clear what I'm trying to do.

Thanks for your help!

Table 1 sample data:

| Number (PK) | Name | Address | Code1 | Code2 | Code 3 | Code 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1587452 | BMW | Downstreet5 | A | 2 | LK | 105 |
| 1887525 | Audi | Abbyroad 7 | A+ | 1 | EFI | 100 |

Table 2 sample data see above

Expected output:

New Query / View with

| Name | Code1 | Description Code 1 | Code2 | Description Code 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BMW | A | potential A | 2 | Mainstream |

What I get:

```
SELECT a.Number, a.Name, a.Code1, b.description, a.Code2, b.description
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table2 b ON a.Code1 = b.Code
```

| BMW    | A | potential A | 2 | potential A | LK | potential A | 105 | potential A |

Solution if someone else does have the same problem:

I solved it with a subquery, like:

```
SELECT a.Number, a.Name, a.Code1,Description =
(SELECT b.description
FROM Table2 b
WHERE a.Code1 = b.Code), 
a.Code2, Description = 
(SELECT b.description
FROM Table2 b
WHERE a.Code2 = b.Code), 
FROM Table1 a
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you show us sample data for the other table as well, and also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: It is not entirely clear. But assuming you just want to look up the descriptions in table 1 to all the codes in table 2, then your current query is not ok because you only made a join on code 1. You would have to create three separate joins to table 1, the first one on code 1, the second on code 2 and the third on code 3.

Comment: If you want to reference the PK made up from `(Type, Code)` , then your **FK** must **ALSO** contain **BOTH** columns - `(FK_Type, FK_Code) ---> PK (Type, Code)` - you **cannot* reference only part of a PK - it's all or nothing

Comment: Is that possible, the way tables are created? If so, how would the query look like?
I have no way to change the tables, FKs or PK

Comment: I solved it with a subquery for the descriptions. Thanks for your help!